# iTextSharp is producing a corrupt PDF

Tags: c#, .net, itext

The code snippet below returns a corrupt PDF document however if I return mergedDocument instead it always returns a valid PDF.  mergedDocument is based on a PDF file i created using Word, whereas completed document is entirely programmatically generated. The code "works" in that it throws no exceptions.  Why is iTextSharp creating a corrupt PDF?

```
byte[] completedDocument = null;            
using (MemoryStream streamCompleted = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (Document document = new Document())
    {                    
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, streamCompleted);
        document.Open();
        copy.Open();                    

        foreach (var item in eventItems)
        {
            byte[] mergedDocument = null;
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplates[item.DataTokens[NotifyTokenType.OrganisationID]]);
            using (MemoryStream streamTemplate = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, streamTemplate))
                {
                    foreach (var token in item.DataTokens)
                    {
                        if (stamper.AcroFields.Fields.Any(fld => fld.Key == token.Key.ToString()))
                        {
                            stamper.AcroFields.SetField(token.Key.ToString(), token.Value);
                        }
                    }
                    stamper.FormFlattening = true;
                    stamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
                }

                mergedDocument = new byte[streamTemplate.Length];
                streamTemplate.Position = 0;
                streamTemplate.Read(mergedDocument, 0, (int)streamTemplate.Length);
            }
            reader = new PdfReader(mergedDocument);

            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                document.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4);
                copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, i));
            }
        }
        completedDocument = new byte[streamCompleted.Length];
        streamCompleted.Position = 0;
        streamCompleted.Read(completedDocument, 0, (int)streamCompleted.Length);
    }                
}
return completedDocument;
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to close the `document` and `copy` objects to flush the PDF writing buffer. This, however, causes some problems when trying to read the stream into an array. The fix for that is to use the `ToArray()` method of the `MemoryStream` which still works on closed streams. The changes I made have comments on them.

```
        byte[] completedDocument = null;
        using (MemoryStream streamCompleted = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (Document document = new Document())
            {
                PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, streamCompleted);
                document.Open();
                copy.Open();

                foreach (var item in eventItems)
                {
                    byte[] mergedDocument = null;
                    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplates[item.DataTokens[NotifyTokenType.OrganisationID]]);
                    using (MemoryStream streamTemplate = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, streamTemplate))
                        {
                            foreach (var token in item.DataTokens)
                            {
                                if (stamper.AcroFields.Fields.Any(fld => fld.Key == token.Key.ToString()))
                                {
                                    stamper.AcroFields.SetField(token.Key.ToString(), token.Value);
                                }
                            }
                            stamper.FormFlattening = true;
                            stamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
                        }
                        //Copy the stream's bytes
                        mergedDocument = streamTemplate.ToArray();
                    }
                    reader = new PdfReader(mergedDocument);

                    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                    {
                        document.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4);
                        copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, i));
                    }
                    //Close the document and the copy
                    document.Close();
                    copy.Close();
                }
                //ToArray() can operate on closed streams
                completedDocument = streamCompleted.ToArray();
            }
        }
        return completedDocument;
```

Comment: I would upvote this 1000 times if I could. I was having difficulty merging images and pdfs into a single pdf document, this helped to shed some light on the correct process.

Comment: Thank you, putting memory stream to array solved my problem with getting back empty PDF file!

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure your html doesn't contains hr tag while converting html to pdf

```
hdnEditorText.Value.Replace("\"", "'").Replace("<hr />", "").Replace("<hr/>", "")
```