# Unable to open PDF after it's generated (vb.net) (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, pdf, itext

Sorry for this question, but I'm new in .net and vb.net. I really need your help! I generate a PDF file in asp.net (vb.net). It should be opened in a browser automatically, but it gives an error - Failed to load PDF document. I see it's created on a drive and opens properly. What could be an issue?

```
Protected Sub ExportToPDF(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 50.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F)
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New 
       FileStream(Context.Server.MapPath("~/ejik.pdf"), FileMode.CreateNew))
    pdfDoc.Open()
    pdfDoc.Add(New Paragraph("What is going on?")) 
    pdfDoc.Close()
    Response.Write(pdfDoc)
    Response.End()

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance!

P.S.: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I use iTextSharp to create a PDF

Comment: You probably want to write the bytes of the pdfDoc.

Comment: sorry, not sure what do you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is all wrong. You are creating a web application, and you create an **object** of type `Document` so that you can write a PDF **file** to disk. (Do you even need that file on disk? You are writing a web application!) Then, instead of sending the file to the end user, you write a `Document` **object** to the `Response` *instead of* (the bytes of) the file. That can never work, can it?

It would be better if you created the PDF file in memory first:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
document.Open();
document.Add(Assinatura());
document.Close();
```

Then you take the bytes of that file in memory, and send them to the `Response`:

```
byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
ms.Close();
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=ejik.pdf");
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
Response.End();
```

This is what the comment meant. Instead of `pdfDoc`, you need to send the `byte` array of the PDF file. See also [iTextSharp is producing a corrupt PDF with Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127071/itextsharp-is-producing-a-corrupt-pdf-with-response)

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it!